# Python/Pandas Datetime Conversion of Date in Format DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS.NS PM

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

Running into some issues with datetime conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
mydate = '12-AUG-03 04.16.41.000000 PM'
mydateconv = pd.to_datetime(mydate)
print mydateconv
"2003-08-12 12:00:00"
```

Is there a reason the time is being reset to 12:00:00?

I've also tried other formatting derivations without success.

```
mydateconv = pd.to_datetime(mydate, format = '%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S.%f %p')
```

Any recommendations?

The raw data I'm receiving has dates in the above format, so I'm looking for suggestions on a solution which addresses dates in this format, whether it's the use of stock function or determination that I'll need something a bit more custom because of the format.

Many thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string needs to be: `'%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'`, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [35]:

pd.to_datetime('12-AUG-03 04.16.41.000000 PM', format = '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
Out[35]:
Timestamp('2003-08-12 16:16:41')
```

You had several errors in your format string `'%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S.%f %p'`.

Firstly your months are abbreviated so you should use `b` instead of `m`.

Secondly your time components had dot (`.`)separators not colon (`:`) separators.

Comment: Many thanks for explanation and link to the additional documentation.  This answered my question perfectly and the doc link will be a useful reference.  Thanks again!